# Gradle build subproject depends on other subproject

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project with some subprojects

```
   -rootProject
      --subProjectA
      --subProjectB
```

A depends on B, I want to publish A without publishing B.

I read the Gradle document about multiple project building. The document is https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
It saids if I write this code

```
project(":subProjectA") {
    dependencies {
        compile project(":subProjectB")
    }
}
```

It causes the other project(B) to be built first and adds the jar with the classes of the other project to the classpath(of A)

But in my project it does not work. The result of A jar has only classes of subProjectA.

Is there are some other config which is needed for my project?

Comment: You probably want to look into creating fat jars (e.g. through the [shadow plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/)). However, if you only want to merge the project jar files while keeping the transitive, external (Maven) dependencies out, yet still have them all in a single final pom, I don't have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using kotlin DSL. Hence I will write the code in that. In the `build.gradle.kts` of the project `subProjectA`, use the code below:

```
dependencies {
  implementation(project(":subProjectB"))
}
```

If you want more specific answer, please post gradle files for the `root`, `subProjectA` and `subProjectB` projects.